# MySQL Layout needs validation

Tags: mysql, vb.net, solidworks

I would like to make sure, my table layout is production safe. Maybe you guys could give me some advice about the design. So my table looks like this:

```
AI_Index   PartName   String1   String2 ... String5 ... TINYINT1 TINYINT2 TINYINT3 
1          Example    L         somestuff   morestuff   0        1        0                  
2          Example    X         morestuff   andmore     1        1        1
```

For clarification:

**AI_Index** is AutoIncrementing for each value added. **PartName** represents a filename. All the other strings and tinyints are describing the value **String1**. It will most likely not happen that **PartName** is unique, it will always be about 5-10 times in there. First estimate will bring about 1000 diffenrent parts. So the database will have about 5.000-10.000 rows.

I'm connecting to the DB with VB.NET and the MySQL connector. If you open a Part in SolidWorks, a query will check if the activedoc is present in the **PartName** column. If so, a UserForm will show up, displaying all values from column **String1** with the values from **String2, String3, String4, String5, Tinyint1, Tinyint2 and Tinyint3**. There are about 40 people working with SolidWorks, changing activeparts frequently. That means ~500 queries a minute just checking if the part is present.

My questions are as follows:

1. Does it make sense to add **PartName** as Index? I read many times that a bad index decision can make the database slower.
2. How could a powerful query look like? I suggest if i create a view with a SELECT DISTINCT **PartName** the query for the active part will be faster. Is this right?
3. Does it make sense to create a MySQL function that returns a TINYINT if the ActiveDoc is present in **PartName**? Will the TableView or the function be faster?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT would give you each partname once; it would not be particularly useful once you have already filtered to a single partname.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my idea. I intend to create `VIEW partlist AS
    SELECT DISTINCT
        parts.PartName AS PartName
    FROM
        parts` and then query this new view to check if the part is present!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just:

```
SELECT String1, String2, String3, String4, String5, Tinyint1, Tinyint2, Tinyint3
 WHERE PartName = 'Example';
```

If the result is empty, no need to show the form.  Then you have the data at hand to show right away.  one query, one result set.
DISTINCT will make it slower.  You would have to do some stress testing to see if your server can handle 500 queries per minute as there are a lot of factors besides just the index and query.